# API call with ReactJs Component doesnt work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

I am really new into react and I am understanding several things not (also after recherchings). Therefore I will ask my questions here. In the beforehand I want to apologize for my bad English and the maybe stupid questions.

I have a js class, in which my API is called and a Component class, which should represent the data. I export the function, which calls the API and the Data and importing it in the "index.js" and giving it my Component class as props.

My first problem is, that the function of my API returns the correct value (an array), but when I call this function in the component it returns undefined.

API.js:

```
const BASE_URL = "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com";
const encodeSpaces = (text) => text.replace(/ /g, "%20");
let cache;

function getMovies2() {
  fetch(`${BASE_URL}/films`).then(response =>  response.json())
  .then(movies => {
    cache = movies;
    console.log(movies);
    return movies;
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log("Api Call failed");
  });
 // return movies;
}

//copied and not written by me
function getMovies() {
if (cache !== undefined) return Promise.resolve(cache);

  return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/films`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((movies) =>
      movies.map((movie) => {
        movie.urlEncodedTitle = encodeSpaces(movie.title);
       return movie;
      })
    )
    .then((movies) => {
      cache = movies;
      return movies;
    });
}

//copied and not written by me
function getMovieByTitle(title) {
  if (cache !== undefined)
    return Promise.resolve(cache.find((movie) => movie.title === title));

  title = encodeSpaces(title);

  return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/films?title=${title}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => data[0])
    .then((movie) => {
      movie.urlEncodedTitle = encodeSpaces(title);
      return movie;
    });
}

export { BASE_URL, getMovies, getMovieByTitle, getMovies2};
```

Index.js: (with Component in it)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {getMovies2} from './API/callAPI';
import reactDom from 'react-dom';
import { isCompositeComponentWithType } from 'react-dom/test-utils';


class RenderMovies extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    var renderedOutput = [];
    Promise.resolve(this.props.movie).then(()=>  {
        console.log(this.props.movie);
    });
    // if(movie===undefined) {
    //   console.log("nix");
    //   return  <div><p>API Fheler!</p></div>;
    // } else{
    //   console.log(movie);
    // }
    // Promise.resolve(movie).then((movie) =>{
      // console.log("Hello");
      // renderedOutput = movie.map((item) => {
      //   console.log(item.title);
      // return <div>{item.title}</div>;
      // });
    // });
  
    return(
      <div><p>{renderedOutput}</p></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <RenderMovies movies={getMovies2()}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

(the outcommented code was just testing).
Furthermore I have 2 questions. First: Why does my getMovies2() has a return type of void (you can see it, when you hover your mouse over the function) and Second: As you see the getMovies() function returns a Promise and my question is, what value I will get, when I resolve the Promise, when calling the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does my getMovies2() has a return type of void

This is a void return since you aren't returning anything from the function. If you return the `fetch` call then it will return the Promise `fetch` returns.

```
function getMovies2() {
  return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/films`) // <-- return Promise chain
    .then(response =>  response.json())
    .then(movies => {
      cache = movies;
      console.log(movies);
      return movies;
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log("Api Call failed");
    });
}
```

> As you see the getMovies() function returns a Promise and my question
> is, what value I will get, when I resolve the Promise, when calling
> the function

You don't resolve the Promise, it becomes resolved (or rejected). If it resolves then you should receive the resolved value that you can then chain from.

Given:

```
function getMovies() {
  if (cache !== undefined) return Promise.resolve(cache);

  return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/films`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((movies) =>
      movies.map((movie) => {
        movie.urlEncodedTitle = encodeSpaces(movie.title);
       return movie;
      })
    )
    .then((movies) => {
      cache = movies;
      return movies; // <-- returned resolved value!
    });
}
```

When `getMovies` resolves you will receive the `movies` array.

You can either chain a `thenable`

```
getMovies()
  .then(movies => { ..... })
  .catch(error => {
    // handle promise rejections/processing errors.
  });
```

Or you can define an `async` function and await the resolved value

```
const myFunc = async () => {
  try {
    const movies = await getMovies();
    ...
  } catch(error) {
    // handle promise rejections/processing errors.
  }
};
```

Additionally, you shouldn't be fetching data or any other sort of asynchronous logic in the `render` method as this is to be a pure function free from side-effects, this is what the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods are for.

Comment: So have I understand it correctly that if I want to return anything from an API Call I have to return this value over the fetch function?

Comment: @Niklas I don't quite follow your question, but if by "return this value over the fetch function" you mean "return the result of the fetch function", then yes. `fetch` returns a Promise, so you need to return *that* Promise if you want to eventually handle any resolved/rejected values.